# ValueError: malformed node or string error when parsing lists from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some text stored in a file which looks like this:

```
[10, 1575311969.9649343, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles']
[101, 1575311971.3570273, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles']
```

Now, I want to get this in my code as a 2d list:

```
batches = [[10, 1575311969.9649343, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles'],
           [101, 1575311971.3570273, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles']]
```

I tried using the code

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('runBatchBackup.txt', 'r') as f:
    batches = literal_eval('[' + f.read() + ']')
```

But this resulted in

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x03C72BB0>
```

How can I convert my text file into the format I want?

Comment: Why do you need literal_eval? normal eval should do the trick, no?

Comment: `literal_eval` is much [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/4739755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is newline-delimited but `literal_eval` needs commas delimiting each sublist for it to be parseable. You can add a call to `replace` to perform the conversion from newlines to commas:

```
batches = literal_eval('[' + f.read().replace('\n', ',') + ']')
```

Result:

```
[[10, 1575311969.9649343, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles'], 
[101, 1575311971.3570273, 'Hot Brew', 10, True, 'No tank', 'Organic Red Helles']]
```

Although the above snippet illustrates the problem clearly, I'd recommend using a list comprehension to apply `literal_eval` to each line:

```
batches = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to `literal_eval` each line individually and add them to a list in your program:

```
with open('runBatchBackup.txt', 'r') as f:
    batches = list(map(literal_eval, f))
```